# Can't create production database for Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to create the database for my Rails app in production mode using Postgresql.

When I run the command:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create
```

I get the following error:

```
FATAL:  database "postgres" does not exist
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode", "host"=>"localhost", "database"=>"provenword", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>"password"}
```

I can create a database for older Rails apps that I have. However, only this one gives me this error. How can I get this to work so I can create the database and run the application?

Gem file:

```
..
    gem 'pg'
..
```

Rails Version - 4.2.6

database YML

```
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# default: &default
# user: postgres
# password: password
# pool: 5
# timeout: 5000



development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  database: provenword
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: password
```

Postgresql is installed on my server.

Comment: Is postgres installed in your server? `which psql` will help you to find the postgresql.

Comment: I thought the same-  you want to use postgres and valid gem for that, you might not have it installed on production.

Comment: I beleive `postgresql` expects a database with the same name as the user name, in your case `postgres`, be present. First setup a database with the name `postgres` then you can run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create`.

Comment: Dharam could you put that as the answer so I can accept that. You are correct, it worked

Comment: chell your configuration is correct , seems like postgres is missing in your server

Are you able to login to postgres console and can see the users?

Comment: Yes. I use Navicat lite and I can connect to the server and create databases. When I connect to the postgresql server and create the database manually everything else for using Rails to perform actions on the database works. I just get this error when running rake db:create

Comment: Dharam do you mean that I should change the database from 'provenword' to 'postgres'?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Dharam.

It's work for me as well:

> I beleive `postgresql` expects a database with the same name as the user
>   name, in your case `postgres`, be present. First setup a database with
>   the name `postgres` then you can run `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:create`